# Refactoring Xpath: Multiple expressions under the same parent

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have an Xpath expression as follows:

`//*[@id="my_element"]/table//select|//*[@id="my_element"]/table//input[@type!="hidden"]|//*[@id="my_element"]/table//textarea`

As you can see I want to select three different type of elements `select`,`input[@type!="hidden"]` and `textarea` all within the same parent `//*[@id="my_element"]/table`

Is there a more concise way to write this? I was thinking something like:

`//*[@id="my_element"]/table//(select|input[@type!="hidden"]|textarea)`

but so far my research hasn't yeilded any results. I attempted the same with `(descendant::select|descendant::input)` and `(descendant::select|input)` but it seems these they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your "concise" form is a valid XPath 2.0 expression. So the answer is, use XPath 2.0.